# convert iso date to date with named month and day

Tags: javascript, date, time

my Task is so simple but I need to know how to do it with just js,

I have this date `2021-05-06` I want to convert it to this, `Fri 7 May`.

how to do this?

Comment: what is this date `**2021-05-06**` a string with twice stars around ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and what did you try ? there several chapters about date formating on mdn doc,, did you read them ?

Comment: thanks for your reply,
I'm sorry for twice stars its wrong from me, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const convertDate = (date_string) => {
  let date = new Date(date_string)
  return `${[ 'Sun', 'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu', 'Fri','Sat'][date.getDay()]} ${date.getDate()} ${['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May','June','July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][date.getMonth()]}`;
}

console.log(convertDate('2021-05-06'))
```

Comment: Where the host has a negative timezone offset, that will present values for the previous day, i.e. 5 May, not 6 May,  see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)